# How do I open an email meeting template item instead of an email using VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create a dynamic email where the user is able to send multiple email based on how many data in a column.

The code will follow the textbox word by word and generate in the email body.

I am trying to open an email meeting template item instead of an email.

```vb
Sub send_mass_email()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, place, business As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
    
    i = 2
    'Loop down name column starting at row 2 column 1
    Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
        
        name = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, " ")(0) 'extract first name
        email = Cells(i, 2).Value
        subject = Cells(i, 3).Value
        copy = Cells(i, 4).Value
        business = Cells(i, 5).Value
        place = Cells(i, 6).Value
        
        'replace place holders
        body = Replace(body, "C1", name)
        body = Replace(body, "C5", business)
        body = Replace(body, "C6", place)
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .to = email
            .cc = copy
            .subject = subject
            .body = body
            '.Attachments.Add ("") 'You can add files here
            .display
            '.Send
        End With
        
        'reset body text
        body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"    
End Sub
```

I  tried `olMeeting` but an error occurs:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the VBA documentation [Application.CreateItem method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitem).

Modify this part of the code:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
```

to

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)
```

By changing the parameter of `.CreateItem` method to one of the listed values in [OlItemType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olitemtype), you will achieve the desired effect.